# list only all keys including nested from json object in jquery

Tags: javascript, json

I want to list all the keys(including nested) in from json object in jquery... the keys/ json object is dynamic so program never the format but it will be json for sure

I need a jquery that list only keys from JSON

Following is sample data:

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_text": "Success",
  "count": 6,
  "data": [{
    "date": "2012-02-27",
    "zone": "NORTH ZONE",
    "centre": "CHANDIGARH",
    "commodity": "Tea Loose",
    "price": "265"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-24",
    "zone": "NORTH ZONE",
    "centre": "CHANDIGARH",
    "commodity": "Tea Loose",
    "price": "265"
  }]
}
```

From above JSON I want to list only keys.

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: that doesnt return nested keys!

Comment: Can you give a sample of what you'd expect it to look like? Is a flat array of keys ok, or do you need an object?

Comment: just google for recursive key search on json objects... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638774/recursively-search-in-json-or-javascript-object

Comment: i just need flat array of keys but all ( including nested) or either only the most inner/deepest keys in array....ThankQ in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
var jsonArray={ "status_code": 200, "status_text": "Success", "count": 6, "data": [ { "date": "2012-02-27", "zone": "NORTH ZONE", "centre": "CHANDIGARH", "commodity": "Tea Loose", "price": "265" }, { "date": "2012-02-24", "zone": "NORTH ZONE", "centre": "CHANDIGARH", "commodity": "Tea Loose", "price": "265" } ] }
 var L = jsonArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
var obj = jsonArray[i];
for (var j in obj) {
    alert(j);
}
}
```

Try this it will works .

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/2TmaG/)

Comment: n try not to copy other link ans instead giving that link, better provide link rather showing off as if u did it... indian